# Where the WebSocket comes from on the client side

Tags: javascript, html, web, websocket, frontend

I`ve made a socket communication between server-side and the client-side. But where the entity of **WebSocket** comes from?

*Client side code:*

```
var _ws = new WebSocket(...);
```

That should be comming from somewhere?
I mean browser knows the  tag comes from **HTML**, and the *console.log('Hi!');* is a **JavaScript**. But what is the **WebSocket**?

HTML5?

Browser build in object?

Comment: Didn't you wonder where, say, `document` or `window` come from? Same as `WebSocket` they're API that browser exposes to your javascript code.

Comment: It is indeed a browser object

Answer (score 0):

There`s a plenty of questions around WebSockets, which starts like:

> "HTML5 WebSockets how ... ?"

I suppose the complete answer should be:

1. WebSocket is the standard of HTML5. *Historicaly it came from there.*
2. As far as HTML5 has started to be supported by most browsers, WebSockets are available through the browser`s API.

This pictures looks quite similar: (thanks, for link @Roland Stark)

[HTML5 browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=html5)

[WebSockets browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets)

*Please, correct me if I`m wrong. That`s kinda fundamental things, and shame on me to don`t know that*.